# How to remove an object's property

Tags: javascript

I need to remove a property in an object but I don't want null value. For example

```
var ob={'name':"CIAO",'animal':'DOG','house':'HOUSE'}
```

for example I want eliminate 'animal'

```
delete ob.animal;
```

the new Object is:

```
{'name':"CIAO",null,'house':'HOUSE'}
```

I don't want this result I want this:

```
{'name':"CIAO",'house':'HOUSE'}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object?rq=1

Comment: `delete ob[1];` does not delete anything!

Comment: You sure `delete ob[1];` deletes anything?

Comment: I don't see this occurring in node, nor in any browser ... what environment is this occurring in for you

Comment: o be honest `{'name':"CIAO",null,'house':'HOUSE'}` is not even a valid object

Comment: where do you get the content of the object after the deletion of the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (after clarification of the question):

For deleting `animal`, you need this. It deletes the property `animal`.

```
delete ob.animal;
```

There is no `null` value in the object.

```js
var ob = { 'name': "CIAO", 'animal': 'DOG', 'house': 'HOUSE' };
delete ob.animal;
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ob, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write(ob.animal + '<br>');
document.write(typeof ob.animal);
```

Comment: see edited question - claims that `delete ob.animal` results in an invalid javascript object